# Python: In class Foo: x = MyClass() can MyClass know the name of the variable it is assigned to?

Tags: python, serialization, metaclass

I'd like to be able to do the following:

```
class PrintName:
    def __init__( self, obj ):
        print obj._name

class SetName:
    def __init__( self, name = None ): # Default name is None
        self._name = name

class Test:
    f = SetName( ) # No explicit name given
    g = PrintName( f )
```

At this point I'd like python to print 'f', so by the time PrintName( f ) is executed f should know it's name.

Every auto naming solution I found gave the attributes their names after creation.
I've been trying to solve this with metaclasses but even that doesn't seem to work.

I'd like to do this to be able to 'save' and 'reload' the python code for later use ( kind of like a primitive scripting language that can be changed in a program with on-use-evaluation )

For example:

```
x = 0
y = 0
p = ( x, y )
```

print p resulting in (0,0), then do something with x and y resulting in

```
x = 124
y = -32
p = ( x, y )
```

print p becoming (124,-32).

The simplest way to do this would be to use

```
p = ( 'x', 'y' )
```

but in this case how do we know that 'x' is the name of a variable and not the string 'x'

I've tried writing a simple scripting language for this purpose, but that's a lot of work and if the above could work then whole of the python language could be used in the script.

I'm trying to find a simple and flexible solution for my problem.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: _At this point I'd like python to print 'f'_ - isn't that exactly what it does? What exactly do you want to do here? All your code examples do what you say you want them to do

Comment: A single Python object could have multiple names, how does it know which one you want?

Comment: `x = MyClass(); y = x; print nameOf(y)` - what should that do?

Comment: Even better, many objects may not have a name at all. Consider the intermediate list `[1,2]` created during the evaluation of `[1] + [2] + [3]` (each of those lists, and the intermediate list, is referred to from VM internals, but not from through any Python name). NB the effect you're after is found in a paradigm called reactive programming, which is notoriously hard to retrofit onto imperative programming languages -- if you want to do this in any way resembling "good", you'll have to man up and implement *a lot* yourself.

Comment: 0) Changed the original example to I wanted it to be. 
1) In case of: x = MyClass(); y = x; This should create a new object with a different name. One with 'x' and one with 'y'
2) Anonymous objects should have a generated unique name. ( Example: MyClass000 )

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a solution in Python 3.x using **__*prepare*__**.
Here's a working code explaining what I wanted to do.

```
from collections import MutableMapping

class MDict(MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._d = dict(*args, **kwargs)
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._d[key]
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._d[key] = value
        try:
            self._d[key]._key = key # Let's set the name of the object
        except AttributeError: # Not a good way to handle immutable objects
            pass
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self._d[key]
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._d)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._d)

class MBase(type):
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(metacls, name, bases, **kwargs):
        return MDict()
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, mdct):
        return super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, dict(mdct))
    def __str__( self ):
        return "class {0}(CSub, metaclass=MBase):".format( self.__name__ )

class CSub: # An empty class so we know when to go deeper int print_code
    pass

class Integer:
    def __init__( self, value ):
        self._value = value
    def __str__( self ):
        try: # See if it's a reference
            return "{0} = Integer( {1} )".format( self._key, self._value._key )
        except: # Not it's a number
            return "{0} = Integer( {1} )".format( self._key, self._value )

class Point:
    def __init__( self, x, y ):
        if type( self ) == type( x ): # Check to see if initializing with a reference
            self._x, self._y = x._key, y._key
        else: # It's not reference
            self._x, self._y = x, y
    def __str__( self ):
        try:
            return "{0} = Point( {1}, {2} )".format( self._key, self._x._key, self._y._key )
        except:
            return "{0} = Point( {1}, {2} )".format( self._key, self._x, self._y )


def print_code( cls, indent = 2 ):
    # Print the header
    if indent == 2:
        print( "class Main(metaclass=MBase):" )
    for attr, value in cls.__dict__.items():
        if not attr.startswith( "_" ): # Ignore hidden attributes
            print( " " * indent + str( value ) ) # Use indentation
            if isinstance( value, CSub.__class__ ): # If it's a subclass then process that too
                print_code( value, indent + 2 )

class Main(metaclass=MBase):
    x = Integer( 0 )
    y = Integer( 100 )
    z = Integer( x )
    p1 = Point(x,x)
    p2 = Point(y,y)
    class Sub(CSub, metaclass=MBase):
        p = Point(1,1)
print_code( Main )
```

This way if I change object x then all other objects referencing x will change as well.
What's more I can easily save the code to a text file for later use.

This still needs work but it's a good start.
I hope this will help others looking for something similar.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to work backwards from an object to the name of the variable that holds it, except by iterating through every variable in the current context and checking to see which ones, if any, have a value equal to the given object. That would be relatively slow and messy.

Perhaps a better alternative (although I'm not sure it will work for your purposes) will be to work with the *name* itself, so e.g. instead of passing `f` to `PrintName` (or whatever), you pass `'f'`, the string. If you needed access to the value of the variable in the `PrintName` constructor, you can then access the stack frame above the current one and pick out the variable with the given name. You can use the [inspect module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) to do this, something like this:

```
class PrintName:
    def __init__(self, name):
        # of course you can just print the name
        last_frame = inspect.stack()[1]
        if name in last_frame.f_locals:
            value = last_frame.f_locals[name]
        elif name in last_frame.f_globals:
            value = last_frame.f_globals[name]
        # do stuff with value
```

Needless to say, this is quite hackish and not the sort of thing you should be doing in any normal program. It's meant to be used in something like a debugger.